Main idea behind one-parameter groups of $*$-automorphisms
I am reading the basic theory of locally compact quantum groups, and one of the main concepts covered currently is one parameter groups of $*$-automorphisms for a Von Neumann algebra $M \subset B(H)$.  I.e, a group homomorphism $\sigma: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \text{Aut}(M)$.
I have covered what the text gives as a motivating example, but I am left unsatisfied since I don't really see the main point behind these objects.  This is a basic summary of the motivating example.

Let $M = M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and let $\tau = \text{Tr}(\cdot)$.  Then positive faithful linear functionals on $M$ are all 'tracially implemented' in the sense that for all $\varphi \in M^{*}_{+}$, there exists a positive invertible element $\delta \in M$ such that $\varphi(x) = \tau(x\delta)$ for all $x \in M$, and moreover that: $$\varphi(xy) = \varphi(y\delta x \delta^{-1}) \: \: \forall x,y \in M.$$  So in a sense, $\delta$ is a measure of how 'far away' $\varphi$ is from being tracial.  Via the functional calculus we can then use this element $\delta \in M$ to define a one parameter group of $*$-automorphisms $\sigma: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \text{Aut}(M)$ by $\sigma_t(x) = \delta^{it}x\delta^{-it}$.  Moreover because we have access to such a nice element $\delta$ (in that $\sigma$ acts in an inner fashion), we can obvious extend $\sigma: \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \text{Aut}(M)$ by $\sigma_z(x) := \delta^{iz}x\delta^{-i\overline{z}}$ so that: $$\varphi(xy) = \varphi(y\sigma_{-i}(x)) \: \: \forall x,y \in M.$$

So In general I understand that if handed a one-parameter group of $*$-automorphisms $\sigma: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \text{Aut}(M)$, one doesn't always have access to some nice element $\delta$, and thus must use analytic function theory to define an 'analytic' extension of $\sigma$.  All of that is fine to me, but I still don't seem to see what the point of the above example is.
Is the main point that for $M = M_n(\mathbb{C})$, every NSF weight $\varphi$ on $M$ is just a positive faithful linear functional, and so the above example is somehow a special case of the Tomita-Takesaki theorem ($\textit{Every NSF weight $\varphi$ on a Von Neumann algebra $M$ comes with a unique one parameter group of $*$-automorphisms $\sigma^{\varphi}$}$). Is this somehow useful because it allows you to compute things with a weight better?  What is the main benefit of having this result at your disposal, and what is the use in relation to locally compact quantum groups?
Thank you.
